# Object conversion with JavaScript UDF in Snowflake (floats)

Tags: javascript, floating-point, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Consider the following JavaScript UDF in Snowflake:

```
create or replace function PUBLIC.TEST(F FLOAT)
    returns VARIANT
    language JAVASCRIPT
    returns NULL on NULL INPUT
    immutable
    comment = 'Test.'
as
    $$
        try {
            return F;
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    $$
;
```

This function receives a FLOAT value and returns it as a VARIANT. For instance,

`select PUBLIC.TEST(-73.60738);`

returns

`-7.360738000000001e+01`

Not bad but I must admit I'm a bit annoyed with the exponential notation and the floating-point arithmetic, especially since a similar function returning a float instead returns the value as received. And such a result is not consistant with a simple SQL statement such as

`select -73.60738::VARIANT;`

which returns

`-73.60738`

Obviously, such a function is quite useless but I wrote it while trying to figure out the causes of a similar annoyance with a real use case, namely, reversing the order of the vertices of a given geometry in a GEOGRAPHY value. For my real use case, I developed a function (ST_REVERSE) that receives a GEOGRAPHY as a parameter and reverse the order of the vertices of its geometries using simple array operations (I can forward the code if anyone is interested) but I'm somehow disappointed when I see that

`select PUBLIC.ST_REVERSE(TO_GEOGRAPHY('LINESTRING (-73.60746 45.52045, -73.60744 45.52050, -73.60738 45.52053, -73.60730 45.52056, -73.60718 45.52058, -73.60708 45.52059)'))`

returns

```
{
  "coordinates": [
    [
      -7.360708000000000e+01,
      4.552059000000000e+01
    ],
    [
      -7.360718000000000e+01,
      4.552058000000000e+01
    ],
    [
      -7.360730000000000e+01,
      4.552056000000000e+01
    ],
    [
      -7.360738000000001e+01,
      4.552053000000000e+01
    ],
    [
      -7.360744000000000e+01,
      4.552050000000000e+01
    ],
    [
      -7.360746000000000e+01,
      4.552045000000000e+01
    ]
  ],
  "type": "LineString"
}
```

Such behaviour makes testing and validation a tad more challenging for the human eye but, more to the point, it greatly increases the size of data exported as GeoJSON downstream.

Are such results expected? Can anyone provide explanations and/or some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround for your specific issue rather than a general fix. Your coordinates appear to have 6 decimal places. You can use the JavaScript number.toFixed() function.

```
create or replace function PUBLIC.TEST(F FLOAT)
    returns VARIANT
    language JAVASCRIPT
    returns NULL on NULL INPUT
    immutable
    comment = 'Test.'
as
    $$
        try {
            return F.toFixed(6);
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    $$
;
```

This may create minor problems of its own that you should be able to workaround. For example, the output of the function is double quoted. For your larger function with a JSON of coordinates, that should be fixable. The numbers will also have trailing zeros, which in the JSON should just be ignored by whatever is reading them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, as a workaround, I figured as much. For my test case, I can easily add a TEST_SQL SQL UDF that calls your JavaScript UDF (or mine), something like `PUBLIC.TEST(F)::FLOAT`: the input value is returned as originally entered/displayed.  However, for my real use case, that is, reversing the order of vertices in a geometry, things get a little bit uglier, not to say more complex. I will think about it some more. Regards.

Comment: Actually, forget the use of an additional UDF. Both versions of the PUBLIC.TEST JavaScript UDF, mine or yours that uses toFixed(), produce the same result if cast as FLOAT, say, `select TEST.PUBLIC( -73.60738)::FLOAT`: `-73.60738`. With that in mind, I realized that Snowflake seems 1) to handle up to 9 significant decimals in latitude and longitude and 2) to remove non-significant decimals in its WKT representation of geometries. Yes, as far as I can tell, something like `select TO_GEOGRAPHY(ST_ASWKT(PUBLIC.ST_REVERSE(geom)))` returns the expected result, albeit with a small performance hit.